# Ruby - How can i convert a Hash to Json array without "[" turning into ''{"0":"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In javascript I have an `ajax` call sending json to my ruby controller

```
$.ajax({
url: "/email_templates/create_email",
type: "POST",
data: {

    email: email, mjml: mjml
},
success: function(resp) {

},
error: function(resp) {
    console.log('There was an error, please contact support.')
},
});
```

The Json that is being sent over looks like this:

```
{"elements":[{"type":"text","options":{"subSection1":"Text style","font":{"size":16,"sizeOptions":[9,10,11,12,13,14,16,18,24,30,36,48,60,62],"family":"inherit","familyOptions":["inherit","Georgia, serif","'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif","'Times New Roman', Times, serif","Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif","'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif","Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif","'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif","Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif","'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif","Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif","'Courier New', Courier, monospace","'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace"]},"lineHeight":"s2","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","padding":[15,15,15,15],"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."},"id":"id1524503670739RAND99067","component":"textTemplate"},{"type":"button","options":{"subSection1":"Button settings","buttonText":"Click me","linkTo":{"type":"none","typeOptions":["link","email","none"],"link":""},"subSection2":"Border style","border":{"size":1,"radius":3,"color":"#3498DB","style":"solid","styleOptions":["dotted","solid","dashed"]},"subSection3":"Button style","fullWidth":"false","align":"center","buttonBackgroundColor":"#3498DB","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","font":{"size":16,"sizeOptions":[9,10,11,12,13,14,16,18,24,30,36,48,60,62],"color":"#ffffff","weight":"normal","italic":"","weightOptions":["bold","lighter","inherit","initial","normal",100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900],"family":"inherit","familyOptions":["inherit","Georgia, serif","'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif","'Times New Roman', Times, serif","Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif","'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif","Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif","'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif","Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif","'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif","Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif","'Courier New', Courier, monospace","'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace"]},"innerPadding":[12,20,12,20],"margin":[0,0,0,0],"padding":[15,15,15,15]},"id":"id1524503666177RAND67491","component":"buttonTemplate"}],"emailSettings":{"id":"id1524503660421RAND64452","component":"emailSettingsTemplate","options":{"width":600,"paddingTop":50,"paddingBottom":50,"backgroundColor":"#f4f5f4"},"type":"emailSettings"},"html":""}
```

and what im receiving in my controller with

```
def create

body_json = params[:email]

p body_json

end
```

looks like:

```
{"elements"=>{"0"=>{"type"=>"text", "options"=>{"subSection1"=>"Text style", "font"=>{"size"=>"16", "sizeOptions"=>["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "16", "18", "24", "30", "36", "48", "60", "62"], "family"=>"inherit", "familyOptions"=>["inherit", "Georgia, serif", "'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif", "'Times New Roman', Times, serif", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", "'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif", "'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif", "Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif", "'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif", "Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif", "'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif", "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif", "'Courier New', Courier, monospace", "'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace"]}, "lineHeight"=>"s2", "backgroundColor"=>"#ffffff", "padding"=>["15", "15", "15", "15"], "text"=>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."}, "id"=>"id1524503161899RAND77809", "component"=>"textTemplate"}, "1"=>{"type"=>"button", "options"=>{"subSection1"=>"Button settings", "buttonText"=>"Click me", "linkTo"=>{"type"=>"none", "typeOptions"=>["link", "email", "none"], "link"=>""}, "subSection2"=>"Border style", "border"=>{"size"=>"1", "radius"=>"3", "color"=>"#3498DB", "style"=>"solid", "styleOptions"=>["dotted", "solid", "dashed"]}, "subSection3"=>"Button style", "fullWidth"=>"false", "align"=>"center", "buttonBackgroundColor"=>"#3498DB", "backgroundColor"=>"#ffffff", "font"=>{"size"=>"16", "sizeOptions"=>["9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "16", "18", "24", "30", "36", "48", "60", "62"], "color"=>"#ffffff", "weight"=>"normal", "italic"=>"", "weightOptions"=>["bold", "lighter", "inherit", "initial", "normal", "100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"], "family"=>"inherit", "familyOptions"=>["inherit", "Georgia, serif", "'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif", "'Times New Roman', Times, serif", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif", "'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif", "'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif", "Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif", "'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif", "Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif", "'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif", "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif", "'Courier New', Courier, monospace", "'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace"]}, "innerPadding"=>["12", "20", "12", "20"], "margin"=>["0", "0", "0", "0"], "padding"=>["15", "15", "15", "15"]}, "id"=>"id1524503164308RAND72755", "component"=>"buttonTemplate"}}, "emailSettings"=>{"id"=>"id1524503150293RAND50259", "component"=>"emailSettingsTemplate", "options"=>{"width"=>"600", "paddingTop"=>"50", "paddingBottom"=>"50", "backgroundColor"=>"#f4f5f4"}, "type"=>"emailSettings"}, "html"=>""}
```

So what i usually do in ruby to turn a hash to json is .to_json

but thats giving me this output:

```
{"elements":{"0":{"type":"text","options":{"subSection1":"Text style","font":{"size":"16","sizeOptions":["9","10","11","12","13","14","16","18","24","30","36","48","60","62"],"family":"inherit","familyOptions":["inherit","Georgia, serif","'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif","'Times New Roman', Times, serif","Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif","'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif","Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif","'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif","Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif","'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif","Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif","'Courier New', Courier, monospace","'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace"]},"lineHeight":"s2","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","padding":["15","15","15","15"],"text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisci elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."},"id":"id1524503835438RAND4461","component":"textTemplate"},"1":{"type":"button","options":{"subSection1":"Button settings","buttonText":"Click me","linkTo":{"type":"none","typeOptions":["link","email","none"],"link":""},"subSection2":"Border style","border":{"size":"1","radius":"3","color":"#3498DB","style":"solid","styleOptions":["dotted","solid","dashed"]},"subSection3":"Button style","fullWidth":"false","align":"center","buttonBackgroundColor":"#3498DB","backgroundColor":"#ffffff","font":{"size":"16","sizeOptions":["9","10","11","12","13","14","16","18","24","30","36","48","60","62"],"color":"#ffffff","weight":"normal","italic":"","weightOptions":["bold","lighter","inherit","initial","normal","100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900"],"family":"inherit","familyOptions":["inherit","Georgia, serif","'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif","'Times New Roman', Times, serif","Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif","'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif","'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif","Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif","'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif","Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif","'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif","Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif","'Courier New', Courier, monospace","'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace"]},"innerPadding":["12","20","12","20"],"margin":["0","0","0","0"],"padding":["15","15","15","15"]},"id":"id1524503838073RAND14158","component":"buttonTemplate"}},"emailSettings":{"id":"id1524503495697RAND55315","component":"emailSettingsTemplate","options":{"width":"600","paddingTop":"50","paddingBottom":"50","backgroundColor":"#f4f5f4"},"type":"emailSettings"},"html":""}
```

Why is it changing the

```
{"elements":[{"type"
```

to

```
{"elements":{"0":{"type"
```

I need to save it to the DB exactly how im sending it from javascript but i cant seem to get it into the correct format. Could someone please help me and explain to me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: the issue seems to be that `elements` changes from an Array to a Hash.
Check your controller code..

Comment: I tried to convert your hash and I find no problems, back and forth. As I understand your question. Stored the hash you posted into `hash_data`, then `puts json_data = hash_data.to_json
puts JSON.parse(data_json)`

Comment: @Tilo all i am doing in my controller is converting it to_json and printing it and i am also printing what the ajax call is sending over, i'm not sure if i should be converting the hash into json another way?

Comment: @iGian it was converting it correctly. My issue was on the javascript side! I had to use JSON.stringify before sending it over, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Can you post your code on how you are calling to_json. It looks like the internal array is getting covered to a Hash

Answer (score 0):

My issues ended up being on the Javascript side and not ruby

```
$.ajax({
url: "/email_templates/create_email",
type: "POST",
data: {

    email:email, mjml: mjml
},
success: function(resp) {

},
error: function(resp) {
    console.log('There was an error, please contact support.')
},
});
```

i was sending over `email:email` when i should've been doing `JSON.stringify(email)`